# Matplotlib figure size

Tags: matplotlib

I have been experimenting with Matplotlib (see recent question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872500/imshow-not-showing-image-correctly))

I am trying to modify the size of the graph output by experimenting with:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 12.5))
```

But it never seems to work as expected - I use larger numbers to try to increase the height of the graph but it does not make it smaller.  Any thoughts on making the graph larger.  The link question above has an attached image that I currently get with figsize=(20,12.5).

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you are talking about the figure shown on screen? And the saved figure does indeed scale correctly? Then consider that your screen simply isn't large enough (e.g. a 1920x1080 screen can show a figure of 19.2 by 10.8 inches at 100 dpi).

Comment: So, let me get this straight. You want to stretch the graph height? And, looking at the graph on your previous question. Is it normal that patches are not aligned with the ticks on the `yaxis`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to answer your question, you can use the `aspect` parameter on `imshow()` call.

From the documentation:

> Controls the aspect ratio of the axes. The aspect is of particular relevance for images since it may distort the image, i.e. pixel will not be square.

In this case, I think it does not matter that "pixels" look square, so you could add the `aspect` parameter to the `plt.imshow()` call and set a value.

```
plt.imshow(field_matrix, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap, aspect=7)
```

Now, the `plt.figure(figsize=(20, 12.5))` will increase the size of the figure window but not the graph aspect ratio itself. So, you can choose to remove this line or leave it. I removed it and got this result:
[image: AxisNotAligned]

As I mentioned on my comment above, I don't know if this is what you wanted, but you can see the ticks are not aligned with each patch. So if you want them aligned you can change the `np.arange()` call on your `plt.yticks()` call to something like this:

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(-0.5, 5.5), [utilities.num2pid[k] for k in range(5)])
```

**Output:**

[image: AxisAligned]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah this fixed the problem!